# session variable getting lost sporadically in java

Tags: java, session, servlets, data-loss

I set a userId in the session object on the pageload of homepage of my application like below

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
session.setAttribute("userId", validUserId);
```

When user navigates to different page of the application, I fetch this userId using normal way like below and I save this userId in database later.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String userId = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
```

This works for almost 95 times out of 100 calls. I am able to fetch the userId and store in database, but for 5 calls, all I get is a blank userId object.
I am not able to reproduce this issue in lower environments, so its bit difficult to understand what the issue is.

I have set the automatic expiry of the pages to 20 mins by adding the property in web.xml and then using it in jsp page.

Can some one please guide as to what could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: `session.invalidate()` ?

Comment: session might be invalidate in-between. cross check all session related operations in your code.

Comment: Are you certain that the session has not expired in the 5 cases?  Are you also certain that someone else did not clear the data somehow?

Comment: Even if the session is expired in between, User has to open the homepage again and I am sure if user opens the homepage, I get the userId. I am quite sure nobody cleared the data somehow as access is strictly restricted.

Comment: @iMBMT: Yes, i do use session.invalidate() in my expiry page JSP using scriptlet. i.e I invalidate the session when 20 mins are crossed and display Page expired page. i am unable to understand the scenario in which case this attribute is getting lost.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause.

When i am displaying the expiry page and invalidating the session, if user clicks on back button of the browser, it was displaying the old page again and if data is submitted now, then this variable is not available as session is already invalidated previously. Need to fix back button issue.